# Threeparttable notes overlapping text

Tags: footnotes, threeparttable

I just started using *threeparttable* package.
I was able to insert table notes all around, and they are displaying correctly under each table. My problem is that number tags in the column overlap with cell content, becoming impossible to read and also very ugly.
How can I make so that number tags get their own spacing and not become cluttered? thanks

Here's my MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{tabulary}   
\usepackage{threeparttable}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h] \label{tab: HposHnegAnag}
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{\textbf{Demographic and anamnestic characteristics}}
\begin{tabulary}{\textwidth}{LL}
Characteristics & Value\\
Height & 1.80 m\\
Weight & 75 kg\\
BMI\tnote{1} & 23.14\\
\end{tabulary}
\begin{tablenotes}
\item[1] Body Mass Index
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I cannot see a problem. Please provide an image which shows your problem. If you need only some more vertical space use `\begin{tabulary}{\textwidth}{>{\rule{0pt}{2.5ex}}LL}`